# display the data in subject table using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have this Database Diagram and im using sql join to get the specific subjects for student. How can i get the data in the **Subject Table** in the specific `studentID`.

i have this query 
**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT Student_Subject.OfferCode, Student.StudentID
FROM Student INNER JOIN Student_Subject
ON Student.StudentID = Student_Subject.StudentID
```

but only displays the `OfferCode` and `StudentID`. How can i display the columns available in the **Subject Table**?
[image: Relationship Database diagram]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPwZn.png)

Comment: JOIN that table too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Join the other table. Try to use alias to improve reading

```
SELECT S.*, Su.*
FROM Student AS S
INNER JOIN Student_Subject AS SS
    ON S.StudentID = SS.StudentID
INNER JOIN Subject AS Su
    ON SS.OfferCode = Su.OfferCode
```